# Passing parameter that does not exist to method

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java proramming, as I have already stated in the title I want to pass some parameters that could or could not exist as instances of a class. If it does not exist, I want to create it. My code so far:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person Ted = new Person();
    Person Jack = new Person();
    Item it = new Item(Ted);
    Item itSec = new Item (Pierce); //Person Pierce doesn't exist => should be created
}
}

public class Person {
public Person(){
    //some code
}
}

public class Item {

public Item(Person name){
    if(!(name instanceof Person)){
        Person name = new Person(); //create that missing instance
    }
    else{
        //some code
    }

void getItem(Person name){
    System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

Comment: You can make use of `0-arg` constructor in that case.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If `Pierce` isn't even *declared* then the code won't compile.  You can pass a declared variable which isn't initialized (is `null`), but you can't pass a variable that *doesn't exist*.

Comment: I want to find a way to pass the parameter; if it doesn't exist it should be created. Any ideas?

Comment: @jedi_mind_java: `"if it doesn't exist"` - But you already know *at compile time* that it doesn't exist.  (Which is why this code doesn't compile.)  There is no "if", it's not in question at all.  It doesn't exist.  You have to make it exist first, just as you already do with other variables.  It's really not clear at all what you're trying to achieve or why.  You already know how to declare a variable, so why not do that?

Comment: It's telling you if `Pierce` doesn't exist as an instance of `Person`, create that instance. `snr`'s and `David`'s answers are correct.

Comment: @David In the compile time, there's actually not a single problem to create it. But I want to implement keyboard input, so - I guess - there's going to throw me an exception. Do you believe is there anyway around I could pass a parameter as a string or object to the constructor Item so it could create the object itself?

Comment: @jedi_mind_java: I suspect there's a more applicable data structure to achieve what you're trying to achieve.  Such as a hash map or any sort of key/value pair where the "name" is the key and the object is the value.  Java won't auto-declare variables for you, but depending on your goal here there are data structures which can help.  Can you better describe the goal here?

Comment: @jedi_mind_java: I've updated my answer below with an idea that may be what you're looking for, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @David Let's face a real life problem, let's assume I am currently running a warehouse. I am receiving t-shirts/dresses etc. I want to sort those clothes according to their brand. So when in runtime I can't actually remember if a given brand is already declared, or even worse if it had been collected by gc. So i want to create that instance of brand.

Comment: @jedi_mind_java: In such a real-life scenario you'd really want to make use of more meaningful data structures, and not simple variables all inside the `main()` method.  Variables themselves don't syntactically do what you're trying to do.  But you can arrange objects into meaningful models and data structures which have that logic built in.  Imagine for example a class `Inventory` which has an operation to add a `Product`.  Within that operation, `Inventory` checks its internal collections/maps/etc. if the `Brand` exists, adds it, adds the `Product`, etc.

Comment: @David could you provide me with some code? or a link to another stack thread?

Comment: @jedi_mind_java: The example in my answer may be a good place to start.  I'm not entirely familiar with Java's collection types regarding specific implementations (not nearly as much as I am with C# anyway), but more just familiar with the conceptual data structures.  A `Map<>` seems like a good enough place to start though.  A Google search for that particular structure in Java seems to turn up some useful examples, I imagine you could pick and choose which ones speak more clearly to you.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand some things.

**You can't use an identifier before it's been declared.** The following is not correct in your code:

`Item itSec = new Item (Pierce);`

That's because you didn't declare `Pierce` before this line. You don't have to create an instance of the class, but you need a valid identifier. You should have declared it before this way:

`Person Pierce;`

At this moment the identifier, or the reference, is empty, so to say, or it is equal `null`. All object references which are not local are initiated this way, or they are equal `false` or `0`, whichever is correct for their type. The result is the same as if you declared explicitly:

`Person Pierce = null;`

But let's move on. Say the reference has been declared. (Btw, Java uses `camelCaseNotation` for variables, so `pierce` would be correct.) Let's say we're at a point when `Pierce` is null or refers to some object, we don't know. Now we call this:

`Item itSec = new Item (Pierce);`

`new Item(Pierce)` calls the constructor `public Item(Person name){...}` in the class Item, which you should know. But now, in that constructor there's the line:

`if(!(name instanceof Person)){`

which you misuse. What this line is checking is not if the variable `name` equals null or an existing object, but **variable type of `name` is a subtype of `Person`**. Which will always return true in this place, as the function heading `public Item(Person name){...}` says this: the function is public, is a constructor, and the argument is of type `Person` (so `Person` or a subtype).

What you want to say here is this:

```
public Item(Person name){
    if(name==null)){ //if the reference is empty
        this.name = new Person(); //I'll explain this below
    }
    else{
        this.name = name; //otherwise the local "name" will stay null
    }
}
```

I used `this.name` and it was a jump ahead. Why? In your code that is `Person name = ...`, which is not correct as that `name` wouldn't last once the constructor's finished. You need a field in the `Item` class object, which will hold this value. So the `Item` class might be defined this way:

```
public class Item {
Person name;
//...
}
```

And now the field `name` holds the value assigned in the line:

`this.name = new Person();`

You need to use `this` to disambiguate which `name` you means. One is the Item class field, the other one is `Person name` the constructor parameter.

Now, we go back to the `main` function. If you want the variable `Pierce` to reference the newly created `Person`, this still needs to be done. The assignment can take place here, but first you'd have to create a function in the class `Item` that returns the value of its field `name`. So:

```
getName() {
    return name;
}
```

And now call it from the `main` function:

`Pierce = itSec.getName();`

That's it. Finally, this function doesn't make sense:

```
void getItem(Person name){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

It doesn't *get* any Item. It only prints what you pass to it. And this doesn't mean that if you call it with `getItem(Pierce)`, you will see "Pierce" on the screen. It will call the toString function in the object Pierce denotes, and as it is, you will get a standard object identifier. But if you define a function:

```
void printItem() {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Then you can call it this way. For an existing object `itSec`:

`itSec.printItem();`

As for a getter function, it should return what you ask for, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect without instancing?

```
Person Pierce = new Person();
Item itSec = new Item (Pierce);
```

Comment: Well, exactly I want that instance being self-constructed if it doesn't exist. I could make the constructor of Item(String name), but in that situation I don't know how to create the instance     Person name = new Person();

Comment: you can but what do you expect with a reference in the method? You should add new constructor with String parameter in Person class. For every person do you think to create new reference? It's useless @jedi_mind_java

Answer (score 0):

```
Item itSec = new Item (Pierce); //Person Pierce doesn't exist => should be created
```

> If it does not exist, I want to create it.

There's no "if" about it.  The code never declared that variable, so it will *never* exist.  (And never compile in its current state.  Surely your Java compiler is telling you this.)  Given that it *always* needs to be created, just create it:

```
Person Pierce = new Person();
Item itSec = new Item(Pierce);
```

---

**Edit:** Based on ongoing comments, it *sounds like* you want to have something more like a `Map`.  Consider an example:

```
Map<String,Person> people = new HashMap<String,Person>();
people.put("Pierce", new Person());
```

The `Map` would basically be a collection of key/value pairs where the name is the key and the `Person` is the value.  You can dynamically add/edit/remove elements to the collection as you see fit.

Then to use it, you'd call another operation on the map:

```
Item itSec = new Item(people.get("Pierce"));
```

You could use various operations to check if a value exists in the collection, add it, etc.  You might even extend the class to add your own operations which create one if it doesn't exist when trying to get it.

Java won't dynamically create variables for you if a variable doesn't exist, but operations on a `Map` (or potentially other similar structures) can check if an element exists, add it, remove it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable that does not exist...

```
Item itSec = new Item (Pierce);
```

The snippet above will never work because `Pierce` is undefined.

The code:

```
 if(!(name instanceof Person)){
    Person name = new Person(); //create that missing instance
}
```

Does not really make any sense, because that is the same as calling

```
Person Ted = new Person();
Person Jack = new Person();
```

Wherein the Person instance does not actually contain any data (unless you have some magic going on when instantiating the `Person`!)

I assume what you really want to pass is not an object whose variable is the name of a person, but rather a `Person` object that contains the name of the person.

If so, your code should be like this:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Ted");
Person p2 = new Person("Jack");
```

If you *really* want to do some instantiation if something does not exist, you *might* be able to do something like this:

```
Item(String personName) {
  if(isExisting(personName)) {
    getPerson(personName);
  } else {
    Person p = new Person(personName);
}

boolean isExisting(String personName) {
  // Check if person exists somewhere
}

Person getPerson(String personName) {
  // Retrieve the Person instance with the same person name.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(!(name instanceof Person)){
      Person name = new Person(); 
    }
```

is meaning less because 'name' is always object is instance of person in this situation.. 
          Item itSec = new Item (Pierce);
          Pierce is not an object.. We can pass only Person object to constructor of Item class.. There is no any method to create an object of any class by just passing unkown variable..